# Merge two images with different size so that they overlap correctly

Tags: java, java-2d

I have two images with different sizes. I want to merge these two images so that the front images overlays correctly the background image.

background (width:144 height:147): [image]

front: (width:227 height:238) [image]

Currently my result looks like this, but i need it to overlay perfectly
[image]

My approach is.
I am resizing the smaller image to the bigger one. For that I am using the a external lib named imgscalr (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.imgscalr/imgscalr-lib/4.2).
As you can see result image is not correct, so I tried to scale the front image so that it overlay the background, also I changed the root of the x / y when I draw the front image on the background but i still have a difference. Any idea how I can merge the two images, so that the strokes image (front) overlays the background.

```
public static byte[] mergeBackgroundWithStrokes(byte[] backgroundImage, byte[] frontImage)
        throws IOException, PDProcessingException {

    Path backgroundfile = readAllBytes(backgroundImage, "background");
    Path outputFile = Files.createTempFile("output", ".png");

    BufferedImage backgroundBuffImg = ImageIO.read(backgroundfile.toFile());
    BufferedImage frontBuffImg = makeColorTransparent(frontImage, Color.WHITE);

    int width = Math.max(backgroundBuffImg.getWidth(), frontBuffImg.getWidth());
    int height = Math.max(backgroundBuffImg.getHeight(), frontBuffImg.getHeight());
    backgroundBuffImg = resize(backgroundBuffImg, width, height);
    //scaling front image
    int scaledWidth = (int) ((width));
    int scaledHeight = (int) ((height) * 1.02);
    frontBuffImg = resize(frontBuffImg, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);

    BufferedImage newImage = mergeImages(backgroundBuffImg, frontBuffImg);
    ImageIO.write(newImage, "PNG", outputFile.toFile());

    return Files.readAllBytes(outputFile);
}

public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int width, int height) 
{
    if (img.getWidth() == width && img.getHeight() == height) {
        return img;
    } else {
        return Scalr.resize(img, width, height);
    }
}

public static BufferedImage mergeImages(BufferedImage background, BufferedImage front) {
    int width = background.getWidth();
    int height = background.getHeight();

    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(front, 15, -10, background.getWidth(), background.getHeight(), 0, 0, width, height, null);
    return newImage;
}
```

Here you can see the complete class: https://pastebin.com/F4VrBwRv